# Include npm dependency in karma

Tags: npm, karma-runner

How can I include a dependency in `package.json` (not a `devDependency`) in karma?

I can include the file in `node_modules/<dependency>`, but I was looking for something more generic, including the main file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any other better way to include them in `karma.conf.js` than

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    var cfg = {
        frameworks: ["jasmine", "commonjs"]
        , files: [
            {pattern: "node_modules/" + deps + "/*.js", included: true, watched: false}
            , ...
        ]
        ...
    };
    cfg.preprocessors["node_modules/" + deps + "/**/*.js"] =  ["commonjs"];
    config.set(cfg);
};
```